# Call user-defined Python functions in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I'm defining two functions in `Hello.py`

```
def Hello(name):
    print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")

def calc(a,b):
    return a**b
```

Then, I use

```
% Call function Hello() defined in Hello.py
py.Hello.Hello('John')
% Call function calc() defined in Hello.py
py.Hello.calc(6,2)
```

in MATLAB.

The first commond gives me good result: "Hello, Don. Good morning!", which is correct.

But error occurs at the second function: "Unable to resolve the name py.Hello.calc.", which puzzles me.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi user2537712. Just checking: Have you restarted Matlab or [reloaded the Hello Python module](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-modified-python-module.html) since adding that `calc()` function? Unlike M-code, Python files used in Matlab do not automatically get reloaded when they are modified.

Comment: Try renaming `Hello.py` to something like `mymod.py`

Comment: Renaming to some other name works!!